# Cannot see notifications-inbox after logging in

Tags: bug

When Unix Stackexchange logs me in whenever I come from another site for the first time, I see I have some new messages in Inbox under the StackExchange top left bar. When I try to check those out, I see a blank window instead of any messages. Here is a snapshot

[image]

I am seeing this on Chrome Version 29.0.1547.57 on my Mac OSX 10.8.4.

Note: This does not happen with any of the other tabs under that window like all sites or notifications. This behavior does not repeat when I see the site on a different tab. Thus this seems very specific to that 1st time when the user signs up as a new user.

Steps to Reproduce.

1. Create an account on Stackoverflow (Could work with other sites but I know of stackoverflow)
2. Visit the stackexchange site https://unix.stackexchange.com/
3. Sign up via the Stackexchange signup option.
4. Site redirects to log you in and nothing is visible under Inbox.

Let me know if I can provide more information or if I should paste this somewhere else.

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions in the JavaScript console or the network tab of the developer tools (F12)?